# Is there a method to suppress default GCC compiler options?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, compiler-optimization, default-value

I want to compile a C-code with only the compiler options I specifically mention. Therefore I need to somehow disable all compiler options that are set automatically. How can I disable the default GCC options that are set during every compilation and are not visible. I am talking about the compiler options that are visible using the following command `gcc -Q -v example.c` leading to this output:

```
GNU C (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) version 4.8.4 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 5.1.3, MPFR version 3.1.2-p3, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
options passed:  -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu example.c -mtune=generic
 -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector -Wformat -Wformat-security
options enabled:  -faggressive-loop-optimizations
 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fauto-inc-dec -fbranch-count-reg -fcommon
 -fdelete-null-pointer-checks -fdwarf2-cfi-asm -fearly-inlining
 -feliminate-unused-debug-types -ffunction-cse -fgcse-lm -fgnu-runtime
 -fgnu-unique -fident -finline-atomics -fira-hoist-pressure
 -fira-share-save-slots -fira-share-spill-slots -fivopts
 -fkeep-static-consts -fleading-underscore -fmath-errno
 -fmerge-debug-strings -fmove-loop-invariants -fpeephole
 -fprefetch-loop-arrays -freg-struct-return -fsched-critical-path-heuristic
 -fsched-dep-count-heuristic -fsched-group-heuristic -fsched-interblock
 -fsched-last-insn-heuristic -fsched-rank-heuristic -fsched-spec
 -fsched-spec-insn-heuristic -fsched-stalled-insns-dep -fshow-column
 -fsigned-zeros -fsplit-ivs-in-unroller -fstack-protector
 -fstrict-volatile-bitfields -fsync-libcalls -ftrapping-math
 -ftree-coalesce-vars -ftree-cselim -ftree-forwprop -ftree-loop-if-convert
 -ftree-loop-im -ftree-loop-ivcanon -ftree-loop-optimize
 -ftree-parallelize-loops= -ftree-phiprop -ftree-pta -ftree-reassoc
 -ftree-scev-cprop -ftree-slp-vectorize -ftree-vect-loop-version
 -funit-at-a-time -funwind-tables -fvar-tracking -fvar-tracking-assignments
 -fzero-initialized-in-bss -m128bit-long-double -m64 -m80387
 -maccumulate-outgoing-args -malign-stringops -mfancy-math-387
 -mfp-ret-in-387 -mfxsr -mglibc -mieee-fp -mlong-double-80 -mmmx -mno-sse4
 -mpush-args -mred-zone -msse -msse2 -mtls-direct-seg-refs
Compiler executable checksum: a0a649d344b1ed798e33d30772d46437
```

Here the default compiler options can be seen as `options enabled`. How can I disable these options without using e.g. `-fno-...` for most of them. Is there an easy way to properly disable the default compiler options?

Comment: What do you expect to gain from turning off all the `-f...` options? Note that some of these options can't be “turned off” as they choose between two different choices, e.g. `-mlong-double-80` chooses between a 128 bit and 80 bit `long double`.

Comment: I would like to turn off all default compiler options that I am aware of. After that I want to set only the compiler options I actively set. This is necessary to really know what compiler options are activated to compile a certain code.

Comment: @FUZxxl: With all options disabled, gcc processes a dialect similar to that of popular 1990s, which includes many useful features and guarantees that were omitted from the Standard because there were or may have been platforms where their cost would exceed their benefits.  If, for example, code needs to scale a signed value by a positive integer, I think gcc will presently support `x<<=y;` rather than requiring e.g. `x=(int32)((uint32_t)x)<<y);`, but a programmer would have no way of knowing whether the next gcc release would require an extra `-fno-silly-signed-shift` to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following script to generate a list of all turned-off `-f` options:

```
gcc -Q --help=optimizers | sed -e '/^[^[]*$/d' -e 's/ *\[.*$//' -e 's/^  -f/ -fno-/'
```

Save the result in a file named `options.txt` and pass it to gcc with the @-syntax:

```
gcc @options.txt ...
```

Note that this does not “turn off” other options such as `-m...` options. Most of them can't be “turned off” either because they aren't yes/no switches or because doing so would change the ABI.

Comment: Would there be any sane way to ensure that any "optimization" features added to new versions of gcc don't get turned on by default when the compiler is updated?

Comment: @supercat Turning “off” feature flags is not guaranteed to make the compiler any more lenient. gcc is a compiler for standard C; if you want to compile traditional C, consider using a different compiler like pcc.

Comment: "Standard C" is a myth. The One Program Rule makes abundantly clear that the authors of the Standard intended that implementations offer behaviors beyond those explicitly required, since it allows for the possibility (and the rationale acknowledges this) that an implementation could be fully compliant and yet totally useless.  Can you suggest any reason the authors of the Standard mentioned how the majority of existing implementations would treat something like `uint1=ushort1*ushort2;` in cases where the result was between INT_MAX+1u and UINT_MAX, if they didn't intend that implementations...

Comment: ...which had no compelling reason to do otherwise would continue to do so?  In the absence of the type-aliasing rules, the Common Initial Sequence rule, combined with rules about casting between union and member types, would imply that a pointer to a structure could be used to inspect the common initial sequence of another, and it is that ability which makes the Common Initial Sequence rule useful; I see no reason to believe the Standard was ever intended to eliminate that, but gcc provides no Standard-compliant way via which a function can accept a pointer to a structure...

Comment: ...and use it to examine members of the Common Initial Sequence of an arbitrary object, even though reading the Standard with the mindset mandated by the Single Program Rule would indicate that the Standard does define a way--gcc simply ignores it.  If the authors of gcc aren't willing to promise to do anything not mandated by the Standard, why should anyone trust the compiler for anything?

Comment: @supercat Send a bug report to the gcc team. Or use another compiler as I already suggested.